# Thread safe class vs Utility class with all static methods

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

When ever I see a class documented as thread safe, I wonder why it was not designed to be a utility class with all static methods like java.lang.Math, etc.

I'm missing valid driving force whenever I  design a class in the scenarios like no state but chained methods in a single class.

**Example 1**: How about a class A that has a 'thread-safe field' S; I mean, the object  'S' itself is thread-safe. Can we declare all the methods and fields like S in class A to be static.

I hope my explanation is clear enough. Please clarify.

**Note:** Exclude javabeans, property holding classes, etc.. My question was regarding classes which perform some actions based on input params, they might need to make use of other classes as well.

I apologize that I edited the question. First draft was totally ambiguous.

Comment: Take `Timer` as a good example - where would you store instance-specific state? (One timer is not the same as another. Just because there aren't any properties doesn't mean there isn't state.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can easily imagine a situation where a class is required to have state, yet it's also a requirement to be thread-safe. I use queues for worker-threads for example. It *HAS* to be thread-safe and definitely has to have state in it. (namely the elements in the queue)

EDIT:

> Note: Exclude javabeans, property holding classes, etc.. My question was regarding classes which perform some actions based on input params, they might need to make use of other classes as well.

If by that you mean that your question is about truly stateless classes, then -by definition- your observation is correct. Those can almost always be expressed in static utility classes.

EDIT2:

I think you are being somewhat mislead by the fact, that a lot of times when we see `static` we can relax about thread-safety. (Though it's not true in every case, just a rule of thumb) While thread-safety and statelessnes can go hand in hand in a way, static is an orthogonal concept. Furthermore, statelessnes does give you thread safety but thread safety doesn't have to mean stateless. If that would be the case, the whole concept of `synchronized` would be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep, I realize that my question is a bit ambiguous. I was actually focusing on classes which need not have any state.

Comment: I wouldn't say that they can always be expressed in static utility classes. Often, they need to extend an abstract class or implement an interface, be instantiated, stored and passed between objects. Take Collections.EMPTY_LIST, for example. Thread-safe, no state, but it has to be a List. Same for most Comparator implementations.

Comment: @Firefox: Could you update the question to give an example of a class which is documented to be thread-safe and yet has no state then? Timer is a bad example.

Comment: @JBNizet: thanks for the correction, I modified my answer accordingly

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I understand it. I'm trying to find one. I totally misrepresented my doubt with a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

**For testability and since `static` fits OO like fist fits nose.**

Testable code requires that you can CREATE your tested object in a controlled way. I don't want to have to execute someone's code just because it's called from somewhere within object I'm testing. I want to test my object in isolation - assuming it's collaborators work fine. Using static methods from some tools makes me use PowerMock for testability OR kiss isolation good-bye and execute that code as well while I'm testing. Powermock is a problem (since it uses it's own classloader), so is testing more than I want.

Static means procedural code. That's fine sometimes, since procedural is fine sometimes. But try to use OO features (inheritance, polymorphism) with static methods to find another reason when NOT to use `static`.
Simple example illustrating this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-05/01-qa-0504-oo.html?page=1 - by no means exhaustive, but shows the point I hope.
Other examples are listed in @JB Nizet's comment on the answer above.

I know this is a late answer, but honestly, I had my fair share of problems with testing objects using static methods from 'instanceless' classes and the usually sought-after solution aka PowerMock.